# How to stop Proguard from deleting return types?

Tags: java, proguard

I've recently enabled Proguard's obfuscation feature for the first time, and it's finding all the holes in my -keep rules, it seems.

My keep rules are defined using annotations: annotated elements are to be left alone. The ensuing config looks something like this:

```
# Keep the annotation.
-keep @interface org.mozilla.gecko.mozglue.JNITarget

# Keep classes tagged with the annotation.
-keep @org.mozilla.gecko.mozglue.JNITarget class *

# Keep all members of an annotated class.
-keepclassmembers @org.mozilla.gecko.mozglue.JNITarget class * {
    *;
}

# Keep annotated members of any class.
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.mozilla.gecko.mozglue.JNITarget *;
}

# Keep classes which contain at least one annotated element. Split over two directives
# because, according to the developer of ProGuard, "the option -keepclasseswithmembers
# doesn't combine well with the '*' wildcard" (And, indeed, using it causes things to
# be deleted that we want to keep.)
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @org.mozilla.gecko.mozglue.JNITarget <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @org.mozilla.gecko.mozglue.JNITarget <fields>;
}
```

All entry points to Java from Reflection/JNI/etc. are annotated with this (or an equivalently-configured, but better-named) annotation.

Unfortunately, this doesn't stop Proguard from renaming the class used as the return type for a method, thus changing its signature and breaking the entry point.

Javap reveals, for example, that the method with signature:

```
 public org.mozilla.gecko.Tab loadUrl(java.lang.String);
```

comes out of Proguard looking like:

```
 public mt loadUrl(java.lang.String);
```

despite being annotated.

So, what's the mystical -keep syntax to keep dependant classes? It seems strange that, having told it I wish to keep an entry point, it proceeds to corrupt it anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behavior. At some point, in an earlier version, ProGuard automatically kept all return types and parameter types, but it turned out to be unwanted and confusing for many developers.

For instance, for reflection with Class#getMethod, the return type is not relevant.

ProGuard now prints out notes if such a type is not preserved. You can then still add a -keep line for it.

See the ProGuard manual >  Troubleshooting > [Note: the configuration keeps the entry point '...', but not the descriptor class '...'](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)

**Update:**

ProGuard 5.0 beta3 and higher support

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses .......
```

to also automatically keep the classes in the specified field types, return types, and parameter types.

Comment: That generally isn't necessary. Note that the descriptor classes are kept; it's just their names that are not kept. For most code with reflection, that is not a problem. It is only a problem if they are referenced by reflection too, in which case their names indeed need to be preserved with -keep. JNI might be an inconvenient example.